SVG animation and Bootstrap modal problem
I have an SVG animation in a Bootstrap dialog that doesn't start until the modal has finished loading.

Demo: Codepen

This is the SVG
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="spinner" width="60" >
  <radialGradient id='a9' cx='.66' fx='.66' cy='.3125' fy='.3125' gradientTransform='scale(1.5)'>
    <stop offset='0' stop-color='currentColor'/>
    <stop offset='.3' stop-color='currentColor' stop-opacity='.9'/>
    <stop offset='.6' stop-color='currentColor' stop-opacity='.6'/>
    <stop offset='.8' stop-color='currentColor' stop-opacity='.3'/>
    <stop offset='1' stop-color='currentColor' stop-opacity='0'/>
  </radialGradient>
  <circle transform-origin='center' fill='none' stroke='url(#a9)' stroke-width='20' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-dasharray='200 1000' stroke-dashoffset='0' cx='100' cy='100' r='90'>
    <animateTransform type='rotate' attributeName='transform' calcMode='spline' dur='2.5' values='360;0' keyTimes='0;1' keySplines='0 0 1 1' repeatCount='indefinite'/>
  </circle>
  <circle transform-origin='center' fill='none' opacity='.2' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='20' stroke-linecap='round' cx='100' cy='100' r='90'/>
</svg>

Why is this happening? Any suggestions?

Can you write your code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Have you seen the link to Codepen?

CodePens, JSFiddle, all have a tendency to be deleted. That is why SO promotes SO Code Snippets. And Snippets can be copied to answer with one click. tnx

Adding the same SVG spinner to the main body of the pen, the spinner on the modal appears to wait until it can start in sync with the added spinner. This may be due to your SVG using SMIL animations. An SVG that uses CSS animations seems to start immediately.
